# Checking posted contact using php to sent to selected contacts email using mail() function

Tags: php, html, forms, email, post

Hi Everyone,

I am trying to post a form using php mail() function to the person selected in a from a option drop down box.

My drop down box shows

```
<label for="contact">Job Contact:*</label>

<select id='contact' name='contact'>
<option value='' selected='selected'>Please select</option>
<option value='name1'>Name2</option>
<option value='name2'>Name1</option>
</select>
```

Which I get the value.

```
$contact =  $_POST['contact'];
```

Compare with users

```
switch ($contact) {

            case "name1":
            $to         = "name1@example.co.uk";
            break;
            case "name2":
            $to         = "name2@example.co.uk";
            break;

        }
```

mail($to, ..., ..., ...);

I can not see why switch does not work?

if i use $to on its own the form sends.

Any ideas would be a great help.

Comment: `var_dump($to);` before `mail()`. And always use `var_dump()` to output the **actual** value instead of **guessing** it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several points of failure here;

You could try expanding your switch (for debugging purposes only) to do something like this:

```
switch ($contact) {

            case "name1":
            $to         = "name1@example.co.uk";
            break;
            case "name2":
            $to         = "name2@example.co.uk";
            break;
            default:
            var_dump($contact);
            exit();

        }
```

This will force your switch to handle the contents of `$contact` if it desn't match any of the switches.

Secondly, try to make sure that `$to` actually contains a value.

Do this by adding 'var_dump($to); right before the `mail()` function.

This is basic debugging - and I suspect that one of those will tell you where the error is.

Comment: Then `$contact` contains NULL which in turn makes your script not setting the $to and your mail sending fails. Try `var_dump($_POST['contact']);` to see if that POST variable has any contents at all.

Comment: Well, there's your problem; the `$_POST['contact']` doesn't contain any value. All you have to do now is find out why.

Comment: do you think it would make a difference if select contained disabled='disabled'

Comment: Probably - because the browser wouldn't send a disabled input field (since it's disabled).

Comment: This is what the problem was i removed it and it worked sill me thanks for your help.